# Open source tools for text clustering and auto summarization

Tags: open-source, text-processing

My latest project requires measuring similarities among text documents and give each of them some short title. Is there any open source library for those? Or if I must build it myself, is there any tutorial on the subjects? What tools I should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Measuring similarities between text documents you can start with older techniques of document vetor similarity ([check vector space model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model)). You can use latent semantic indexing for the same. [Here is one paper](http://www.linguistik-online.de/17_03/merlo.pdf) on document similarities.

Text summarization is more difficult then similarity measures as you have to produce something meaningful to humans. [OpenNLP](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/opennlp/index.php?title=Main_Page) is good library for all the basic related to text processing. More papers related to text summarization are [here](http://www.summarization.com/), may be good to start with.

Answer (score 2):

You can measure similarity using one of the [edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) functions, there are implementations available for populate languages if you do a search, such as [C# Leventshtein distance.](http://www.dotnetperls.com/levenshtein).

Similarity between documents can also be a problem of [Information Retrieval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_Retrieval), a popular library for which is [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html). Lucene uses the [vector space model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model) to determine similarity between a document and a query and can also be used to measure similarity between two documents. There are implementations in Java and C# and ports to other languages as well.

The problem can also be that of [natural language processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) and among the libraries I have used are [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) and [LingPipe](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/). These libraries are targeted at much more than similarity, they have a steep learning curve and may be overkill. However, these could be helpful in extracting a the short title for a document.